# is it make sense to commit query transactions on Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Should I commit a SELECT transaction on Hibernate and treat exceptions rolling back it? Why or why not?

Answer (score -1):

select queries need not to run inside transaction because it is not modifying any data in DB.
If you are querying the db and  if any exception  occurs , there is no point of rollback because no data has been modified, but in case of update or insert we are playing with data and if any exception occurs then state of DB should be as per before that unit of work.